# How to get status_code from an exception object

Tags: python, exception, httprequest, httpresponse, http-status-codes

In my code I have a get request as:

`response = requests.get(url)`

For invalid status code ie non 2xx an exception is raised,

`exp_obj = RequestException(response)`

Now I want to get the status code from this exception object `exp_obj`

I tried `exp_obj.response.status_code` but I am getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'status_code'`

If I print exp_obj it is same as response object ie `<Response [500]>`

Comment: Clearly, exp_obj.response is None

Comment: why is it none, then is there any other way to get status_code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). But looking at what you are trying to do. You need to check the way `requests.exceptions.RequestException()` [works](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/_modules/requests/exceptions/#RequestException).

```py
class RequestException(IOError):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initialize RequestException with `request` and `response` objects."""
        response = kwargs.pop("response", None)
        self.response = response
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request", None)
        if response is not None and not self.request and hasattr(response, "request"):
            self.request = self.response.request
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

For your `exp_obj` to contain the response, you have to create the RequestException [using named arguments (**kwargs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs). `exp_obj = RequestException(response=response)`

In your case you should be doing this.

```py
>>> response = requests.get("https://httpstat.us/404")
>>> exp_obj = RequestException(response=response)
>>> vars(exp_obj))
{'response': <Response [404]>, 'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>}
>>> exp_obj.response.status_code
404
```

Answer (score 0):

exp_obj.response is None because you never got a response from the URL. That will happen, for example, if the hostname in the URL cannot be found. On the other hand, for example, if the hostname is valid but the sub-domain is invalid (resulting in HTTP 404) then you would have had a response that you can interrogate

Comment: If I print response.status_code I am getting a status code, I want to how to get it from an exception object

Comment: @AbhiramDevisetti If you had a response from the host then E.response.status_code would be correct

Comment: Yeah, but it seems like I have to create an exception using named arguements. thanks!